# Ignite Remote job exception

Tags: scala, maven, kubernetes, breeze, ignite

I have made two deployments in kubernetes GKE, one with the apache-ignite image (https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/stateless-deployment) and another one with my Maven app (using apache-ignite https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xhulja07/igniteconfig/master/ignite-deployment.yaml). My app has a closure `var calls: Collection[IgniteCallable[Double]] = new ArrayList
        calls.add(() => {` which uses breeze inside. When I try running my app only it works fine, but when I run it simultaneously with the other deployment in the cluster, it gives me the following error:

```
`class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Remote job threw user exception (override or 
implement ComputeTask.result(..) method if you would like to have automatic failover for 
this exception): class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedvException: 
breeze.linalg.DenseVector$SerializedFormer 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: breeze.linalg.DenseVector$SerializedForm`
```

Comment: Do you happen to use Peer Class Loading? key/value classes will not be peer loaded. Make sure to deploy jars with your key/value classes (and code if peer loading is off) to your server nodes' classpath.

Comment: Yes its enabled. Sorry Im new to this, what would be my server node's classpath? Also by key/value classes jars you mean the 3rd party libraries like breeze?

Comment: Yes, as well as code of your own tasks. Your server node's classpath is a set of JARs, I'm not sure how to add custom JAR there when running in K8S